# Add NSAccessibilityElement to an existing NSView

Tags: macos, cocoa, accessibility, nsview, appkit

I want to use [MacOS accessibility feature](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/accessibility_for_macos) with my application which renders its own custom UI (i.e. not using Cocoa). For this I implement a tree of subclassed `NSAccessibilityElement`s associated with each widget I draw.
The root UI container is hosted inside an `NSView` provided to my application externally (my application is a plugin). Now I need to attach my tree of `NSAccessibilityElement`s to the existing `NSView` provided by the host.

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/ImplementingAccessibilityforCustomControls.html) recommends two ways to achieve this:

- Reimplement parent's [`accessibilityChildren`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsaccessibility/1535018-accessibilitychildren) property to include custom elements (Qt uses this method for example). Unfortunately I do not create the parent `NSView` myself, it gets injected externally.
- Call [`accessibilityAddChildElement`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsaccessibilityelement/1533717-accessibilityaddchildelement) convenience method. But when I call it on provided `NSView` object, I get an exception that it does not respond to this method.

What would be the right way to attach a tree of `NSAccessibilityElement`s to an exiting `NSView`?

Comment: What accessibility features are you trying to achieve? Did you try the `setAccessibilityX` methods on `NSView`? For example, to set the role of the view: [setAccessibilityRole(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsaccessibilityprotocol/1534297-setaccessibilityrole)

Comment: @smr I can call `setAccessiblityX` method on provided `NSView` except the `accessibilityAddChildElement` one, which is one I was after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I ended up subclassing `NSView` to capture the top level `NSAccessibilityElement`. Overridden `- (NSArray*) accessibilityChildren` method returns that captured accessibility element as one of its children:

```c
@interface AccessibilityRootView : NSView
- (instancetype)initWithAccessibilityElement: (NSAccessibilityElement*)anElement;
@end

@implementation AccessibilityRootView
{
    NSAccessibilityElement* element;
}

- (instancetype) initWithAccessibilityElement: (NSAccessibilityElement*)anElement
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
        element = anElement;

    return self;
}

- (NSArray*) accessibilityChildren
{
    NSArray<NSAccessibilityElement*> *children = [super accessibilityChildren];

    int numKids = (int)[children count] + 1;
    NSMutableArray<NSAccessibilityElement*> *kids = [NSMutableArray<NSAccessibilityElement*> arrayWithCapacity:numKids];

    for (id object in children)
        [kids addObject:object];

    [kids addObject: element];

    return NSAccessibilityUnignoredChildren (kids);
}
@end
```

I then attach this subclassed view of zero size to the parent `NSView` provided by the host:

```c
NSView* hostView = /* host-provided NSView */;
AccessibilityRootView* accessibilityRootView = [[AccessibilityRootView alloc] initWithAccessibilityElement:(NSAccessibilityElement*)topLevelAccessibilityElement];
[hostView addSubview:accessibilityRootView];
[accessibilityRootView release];
```

At this point all my `NSAccessibilityElements` are attached to that zero-size view that lives in the host-provided view, and MacOS can successfully query the items.

Additionally each `NSAccessibilityElement` had to implement correctly its
`- (NSRect)accessibilityFrame` and
`- (id) accessibilityHitTest:(NSPoint)point`
to match the screen position of my custom drawn UI widgets.

Comment: This seems very very close to what I'm trying to achieve right now!

Quick question though - do you propagate the elements to your host view dynamically or only once, on initialization? 

For most part I settled to using `NSAccessibilityPostNotificationWithUserInfo` but that doesn't update the frame... and oh my, it's such a pain to get the frame to work. I'm setting `setAccessibilityFrameInParentSpace` but that doesn't cut it either. I still don't get why `accessibilityAddChildElement` throws the exception, lol...

Comment: @cieplik I do it once when the UI gets constructed (or reconstructed). I have then peer `NSAccessibilityElement` for each non-native UI element. These implement `(NSRect)accessibilityFrame`, as described in my answer, to report the UI elements position correctly. I never call `accessibilityAddChildElement` and `setAccessibilityFrameInParentSpace`, but only implement `accessibilityChildren` and `accessibilityParent` methods, which use hierarchy tree of my non-native widgets to figure out relations between the elements.

Comment: Where did you get `topLevelAccessibilityElement` from?

Comment: I create it myself from subclassed `NSAccessibilityElement`